# Уместно ли использование глагола совершенного вида в повелительном наклонении в паре с глаголом несовершенного вида?

Tags: глаголы

У нас с коллегами завязалась дискуссия на тему уместности использования подобной связки в рамках следующего предложения: "Помешайте им уносить ящики.".

Контекст у этой фразы следующий: группа людей в рамках определённого времени пытается унести как можно большее количество бесчисленных ящиков по одному; другой группе выдаётся приказ всячески препятствовать первой группе до истечения таймера.

Моих коллег смутило использование несовершенного глагола "уносить" в связке с совершенным глаголом "помешайте". Они предложили использовать вместо этого совершенный глагол "унести", потому что так "смотрится легче". Однако, по моему мнению, использование совершенного глагола искажает изначальный посыл фразы.

Дабы отстоять свою точку зрения, я воспользовался Национальным корпусом русского языка в попытках найти примеры употребления, подобные моему (гл. пов. н. + гл. несов. в.). Для глагола "помешайте" были найдены лишь два вхождения, датированные 1870-м и 1914-м годами.

Возникает следующий вопрос: существуют ли в современном русском языке правила, ограничивающие использование глаголов несовершенного вида в связке с глаголами совершенного в повелительном наклонении (конструкции вида "помешайте [что-либо делать]", например)?

Comment: Так повелительное наклонение бывает как у совершенных так и у несовершенных глаголов. И конструкции типа:
Не давайте им уносить ящики. Мешайте им уносить ящики. 
Звучат вполне убедительно.

А вот что делать когда повелительное наклонение у глагола совершенного вида в связке с глаголом несовершенного вида:
Не дайте им уносить ящики. Помешайте им уносить ящики. 
Вопрос интересный. Согласен с друзьями что как-то не звучит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грамматически сочетание может быть *любым*, лишь бы смысл соответствовал тому, что вы хотите сказать. К вашему контексту (они будут уносить по одному, а вы им мешайте) ваш вариант предложения не подходит (он описывает желаемый *результат*, а не предложенные действия), и нужен другой:

> Мешайте им уносить ящики.

К вашему варианту

> Помешайте им уносить ящики.

нужен контекст посложнее, например: *они все равно будут уносить ящики, но вы им помешайте в нужный момент, чтобы отвлечь их внимание на себя, и тогда мы вмешаемся.*

Оставшиеся два сочетания.

> Помешайте им унести ящики.

Соответствующий этому контекст: *сделайте так, чтобы они эти ящики не унесли.*

> Мешайте им унести ящики.

Возможный контекст: *они будут пытаться унести ящики (все вместе), а вы (в ближайшие часы) мешайте им своим присутствием, чтобы затянуть время до нашего прихода.*

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, в нужном контексте то или иное сочетание становится подходящим. Хотя, если расширять тему повелительного наклонения, видов глагола, частицы не и типа глагола, то можно найти и невозможные сочетания. 
Итак, чтобы понять какой контекст подходит, надо заметить, что повелительное наклонение глагола совершенного вида это разовое действие, в то время как для глагола несовершенного вида это длительный процесс. Из этих соображений сразу следует нужный контекст:

> Сначала помешайте *(мешайте - будет ошибкой ибо требуется разовое действие)* им уносить ящики один раз, затем помогите *(помогайте - будет ошибкой ибо требуется разовое действие)* им уносить ящики несколько раз, затем мешайте *(помешайте - будет ошибкой ибо требуется длительное действие)* им уносить ящики один час, затем помогайте *(помогите - будет ошибкой ибо требуется длительное действие)* им уносить ящики два часа, затем помешайте им унести ящики, а если не получится то помогите им унести ящики, а если и это не получится, то оставьте их уносить ящики.

В этом предложении все логично и не требует особых объяснений. Конструкция "Оставьте их уносить ящики" эквивалентна "Оставьте их одних чтобы уносить ящики" и на самом деле не связана с конструкциями в вопросе.